# QueryInterface of out-of-proc COM server on interface imported from TLB

Tags: com, atl, idl, typelib

I define my interfaces in an A.idl file, which I compile to A.tlb

In a VS2005 ATL project "B" I use importlib(A.tlb) in B.idl and #import "A.tlb" in stdafx.h and implement an interface IA from A.tlb in an ATL COM class. The project outputs a B.dll and a B.tlb

I add the B.tlb to refererences of a C# application and within the code I instantiate the COM object.

The instantiation works without problems if I use either

```
Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(); Activator.CreateInstance(...);
```

or

```
[DllImport("ole32.dll", ...)] CoCreateInstance(...)
```

Both work fine, the object instantiates and **I can cast it to IA interface defined in A.tlb** (actually a RCW generated from the tlb) and invoke its methods. Still no problems.

Then I use OLEView to enable the COM object activation using the default DllHost.exe surrogate.

The instantiation of the COM object **within the surrogate** (parameter CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER in CoCreateInstance) is still without problems, but **when I try to cast the object to the IA interface defined in A.tlb I get E_NOINTERFACE** and a message saying QueryInterface failed because "No such interface supported".

Please help. What could be wrong? If you need any additional info, I'll try to provide as much as possible.

Comment: I tried to copy and paste all the idl code from A.idl (struct and interface definitions) to B.idl, removed #import "A.tlb" and voila - I can cast the object created with CoCreateInstance to IA and use it without problems.

This implies that the bug is either in the way the A.tlb is compiled or the way I include/import the tlb or something with registry entries for the interfaces in the tlb.

Any hints regarding how to correctly use interfaces defined in a TLB ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build and register the proxy/stub DLL.  Required to marshal the interfaces across process boundaries.  I can't find a great MSDN page for it, but it is [mentioned here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a0b162x%28VS.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Unfotunately building and registering BPS (generated proxy/stub project) didn't help.
Do I need to edit anything in the PS project manually ?

Comment: Not usually.  Do make sure that everything is getting registered properly.  You have to see your interface IIDs back in HKCR\Interfaces with the proxy CLSID listed.  SysInternals' ProcMon visualizes it, you'll see COM hitting the registry keys looking for the proxy.

Comment: Thanks. In the end the building and registering of the proxy/stub dll solved my problem. A quite good msdn article is here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms688707 plus I had to google solutions to some minor bugs that appeared during the compilation.